# How to capture the element using srcset attribute?

Tags: java, xpath, css-selectors, elements

I'm trying to understand the difference between the `data-srcset` and `srcset` attributes.

I need to get a photo by the `srcset` attribute, but I can only get it using `data-srcset`.

I don’t really understand what the problem is, if the principle by which I get it should be similar.

Let's say I have the following plan `html` code - [html code](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/bea1bf5585b418a07a0fada42b4b1e82).

Scenario `#1`:

when I try to get by `data-srcset` attribute like this:

```
         // class of the whole element
         liElements.forEach(liElement -> {
            
              ...

             // small photo
             Element imgElement = liElement.select("img").first(); // img of element
             String dataSrcElement = imgElement.attr("data-srcset"); // data-srcset for element of img
             //String srcsetElement = imgElement.attr("srcset"); // srcset for element of img
```

then there is no problem, but when I use the `srcset` attribute.

Scenario `#2`:

```
             // class of the whole element
             liElements.forEach(liElement -> {
                
                  ...

                 // small photo
                 Element imgElement = liElement.select("img").first(); // img of element
                 //String dataSrcElement = imgElement.attr("data-srcset"); // data-srcset for element of img
                 String srcsetElement = imgElement.attr("srcset"); // srcset for element of img;
```

I'm attaching the screenshot as a proof below:
[image]

I see that `null`. Can anyone suggest what the difference is?

Is it possible to get it somehow by `srcset`? If yes, how can this be done in your opinion?

[image]

(I need to get the photo for the first product in the existing `forEach()` loop)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Srcset` is a new attribute which allows to specify different kind of images for different `screen`-`sizes`/`orientation`/`display`-`types`. It allows to define a list of different image resources along with size information, so that browser can pick the most appropriate image based on the actual device’s resolution.

`Srcset` gives the browser a choice. A lot of things can be used to select this choice like viewport size, users preferences, network condition and so on.

```
List<WebElementFacade> imageLink = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[srcset]"));

    for (WebElementFacade imageLinks : imageLink) {
        BigMethod.pause(3000);
        if (!imageLinks.isDisplayed()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Descriptors are just a way to show what kind of image is hidden behind the resource.

There are various kinds of descriptors:

1. Density descriptor:

- `srcset="image.jpg, image-2X.jpg 2x" The display density values—the 1x, 2x, etc.—are referred to as display density descriptors`.

2. Width descriptor:

- `srcset="image-240.jpg 240w, image-640.jpg 640w"`.

3. Size descriptor:

- `srcset="image-160.jpg 160w, image-320.jpg 320w, image-640.jpg 640w, image-1280.jpg 1280w" sizes="(max-width: 480px) 100vw, (max-width: 900px) 33vw, 254px">.`

Test automation services achieve better quality with qasource that build test automation environments rapidly. It helps to capture images with srcset attribute.

Test automation services support [image-set()](https://caniuse.com/css-image-set) attribute for a background image in CSS.

Comment: Thank you a lot for sharing, I'll play with your snippet and mark it as accepted a bit later. Now I'm giving upvote for your time and detailed explanation. I appreciate it so much.